# Integrating Behaviour subject into Typescript application

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I tried to integrate rxjs into my typescript project, but ended up with the following errors.

```
BehaviorSubject.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at BehaviorSubject.js:5

testSubject.ts:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BehaviorSubject' of undefined
```

The file which incorporates behaviour subject,

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
     
export class TestProject { 

    constructor() {
        let testString = "Eric";
        let currentNameSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(testString);

        currentNameSubject$.subscribe(val => {
               alert(val);
         });
 

     currentNameSubject$.next('Obama');
     currentNameSubject$.next('Jacob');
 } 
  }
```

the tsconfig.json,

```
"compilerOptions": {
   

    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",  
    "module": "amd", 
    "paths": {  
      "rxjs/*": [ "./node_modules/rxjs/*" ],
      "rxjs-compact/*": [ "./node_modules/rxjs-compact/*" ]       
     },
    "inlineSources": true, 
    "experimentalDecorators": true,  
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "esModuleInterop": true
   }
```

package.json:

```
rxjs: 6.6.7,
 rxjs-compat: 6.6.7,
typescript: 4.2.4
```

Comment: I dont think you can `currentNameSubject$.subscribe`, you need to `currentNameSubject$.asObservable().subscribe`

Comment: thanks, but thats another part, even if I remove that line, I'm not able to run. I tried even with only the first two lines in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

I changed module to "commonjs" and that works for me. "paths" contains aliases, that means you can simplify the attributes to just the package names. Each value of "paths" is a list of paths relative to the "baseURL". That's why you should add it to your tsconfig.json.

Here the test project I'm using:

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "rxjs": [ "node_modules/rxjs/*" ],
      "rxjs-compact": [ "node_modules/rxjs-compact/*" ]
    },
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

#### test.ts

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

export class TestProject {
    constructor() {
        console.log(`it works`);
        let testString = 'Eric';
        let currentNameSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(testString);

        currentNameSubject$.subscribe(val => {
            console.log(val);
        });


        currentNameSubject$.next('Obama');
        currentNameSubject$.next('Jacob');
    }
}

const test = new TestProject();
```

#### Run in NodeJS

```
tsc --sourceMap && node test.js
```

Comment: hey I tried yours, but still the error is coming, `App.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

Comment: what programming language do you use or for what platform are you developing?

Comment: only typescript in frontend and .net in backend